# Py2neo searching error

Tags: flask, neo4j, py2neo

Im still trying to make a social network with py2neo+flask+neo4j.

I've got a problem while searching my database with py2neo.I wanna find all the users that their username includes a special string.For example all the users that their username includes "dav".I wrote the code below and i dont know why i get this error...

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph=Graph("http://neo4j:123@localhost:7474/ ")
def search(name):
   users=graph.merge("Person")
   for N in users:
       print N['username']
```

and this is my error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "", line 1, in 
>       File "/home/ali/Desktop/flask/search.py", line 10, in search users=graph.cypher.execute('match (p:Person) return p'
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/core.py", line  659, in cypher metadata = self.resource.metadata
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/core.py", line 213, in metadata self.get()
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/core.py", line 267, in get raise_from(self.error_class(message, **content), error)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/util.py", line 235, in raise_from raise exception py2neo.error.GraphError: HTTP GET returned response 404

Comment: Please post the complete stack of error messages. Also, the code you're posting doesn't search for anything, it tries incorrectly to create/lookup a new person

Comment: i changed the "users=graph.merge("Person")" part to users=graph.cypher.execute('match (p:Person) return p')
and i still get that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is wrong, you should change it to this:

```
Graph("http://neo4j:123@localhost:7474/db/data")
```

Also, you can't execute cypher through the `merge` function, instead you should do this:

```
users = graph.cypher.execute('match (p:Person) return p')
```

Comment: I dont know whats wrong with it..

actually it worked properly with this:

`users=graph.merge("Person")`

Comment: `graph.merge(label)` is correct, only your URL was wrong